# Resizing content instead of moving it

Tags: html, css, web

I´m using `boostrap 3. I want to place 4 images in columns of 2 images, something like this:

> ```
> ______   ______
>  |Image|  |Image|
>
>  ______   _______
>  |Image|  |Image|
> ```

So the **code** looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <!--Reglamento-->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="Second_web.html">
        <img src="img/test_img.png" width=100%>
        <div class="box_text">
            Reglamento_text
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>

    <!--Armamento-->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="Second_web.html">
            <img src="img/test_img.png" width=100%>
            <div class="box_text">
                Armamento_text
            </div>
        </a>
        </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!--MISC-->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="Second_web.html">
            <img src="img/test_img.png" width=100%>
            <div class="box_text">
                MISC
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.box_text {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

When I resize the screen I want the images to resize and get small, keeping the same proportions, but instead the right column moves and all the images cover the whole screen.

Comment: Use bootstrap default class **img-responsive**.

Comment: Also, the width attribute on the img tag only takes pixel values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-width

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 images in one row, why use `col-sm-2` and not `col-sm-6` ?

Anyway, to answer your question you should read about boostrap3 breaking points. To see where `col-sm` turns into a `100%` width column. You can find more info on [bs3 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

So if you want your columns to always stay 2 on one line add `col-xs` class to them. ( This is in bs3, in bs4 col-xs does not exist. Read change logs about that if you update to bs4, read about bs4 -> [bs4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) )

I changed to `col-6` but you can leave `col-2` if you need it that way.

See below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/96330/)

```css
.box_text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <!--Reglamento-->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="Second_web.html">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width=100%>
        <div class="box_text">
            Reglamento_text
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--Armamento-->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="Second_web.html">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width=100%>
            <div class="box_text">
                Armamento_text
            </div>
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <!--MISC-->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="Second_web.html">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width=100%>
            <div class="box_text">
                MISC
            </div>
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="Second_web.html">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width=100%>
            <div class="box_text">
                MISC
            </div>
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```